# getElementByID for Dynamically generated ID Elements

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am having an issue with getting the value of an `ID` element of the item that is dynamically generated from the data obtained from the database. I have a query `SELECT ItemID, ItemName, ItemImageName FROM Items`. Than I have the following code that will generate `ID` for each `<div>` for all rows returned from the database by concatenating the value of `ItemID` to each ID name.

```
for ($i=0; $i <$numrows; $i++) {
$stmt->fetch()

<div> <img class="itemImage" id="Image" .$ItemID src=/images/itemImage . $itemID> $ItemID </div>
<div id= "ItemID" .$ItemID> $ItemID </div>
<div id= "ItemName" .$ItemID> $ItemName" </div>

}
```

This should return  a similar result to this for an item with `ItemID=002`:

```
<div> <img class="itemImage" id=Image002 src=/images/Image002 > </div>
<div id= ItemID002> 002 </div>
<div id= ItemName002> SomeNameOfItem002" </div>
```

Then I want to be able to click an image with an `ID=Image002` and I want to get a value of `ItemID` with the `getElementById("ItemID").innerHTML`. I have the following code:

```
var itemID = document.getElementById("ItemID").innerHTML;

$( ".itemImage" ).click(function() {
var itemID= document.getElementById("ItemID").innerHTML;
console.log(itemID);
```

This however returns `itemID` as undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the first code-sample php? The syntax looks way off. `<div id= "ItemID" .$ItemID>` doesn't make sense to me, why is the .$itemID prefixed with a period? That loop is outputting several elements with the same id. there should only be one of any given id in the DOM at a time.

Comment: @admcfajn That is PHP code, the append operator in PHP is the period, that code should create something like `<div id="ItemID"002`, OP should fix it to create `div id="ItemID002"`

Comment: Thanks @Ben, and I did know that... I just didn't think it was valid because the concatenate operator (i'd argue that the prepend operator would be `.=` ) is being used outside of PHP from the looks of things, that's why I was confused... No opening or closing php tags or echo/print statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <div> <img class="itemImage" id=Image001 src="/images/Image001"> </div>
        <div id=ItemID001> 001 </div>
        <div id=ItemName001> SomeNameOfItem001" </div>

        <div> <img class="itemImage" id=Image002 src="/images/Image002"> </div>
        <div id=ItemID002> 002 </div>
        <div id=ItemName002> SomeNameOfItem002" </div>

        <div> <img class="itemImage" id=Image003 src="/images/Image003"> </div>
        <div id=ItemID003> 003 </div>
        <div id=ItemName003> SomeNameOfItem003"> </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".itemImage").click(function () {
                    var imgID = $(this).prop('id').replace("Image", "");
                    // you can directly use value imgID variable if its same. or you 
                    //can use from ItemID inner html
                    var yourValue = $("#ItemID" + imgID).html();
                    alert(yourValue);
                })
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById("ItemID").innerHTML` returns undefined, because it is undefined. The correct id is `ItemID002`. You need to be able to tell which it is.

First, change your PHP to create HTML like this.

```
<div id="ItemID002" onclick="clicked(002)" />
```

Then, go to your Javascript and create this function.

```
function clicked(id){
    var itemID= document.getElementById("ItemID"+id).innerHTML;
    console.log(itemID);
}
```

Lastly, you're PHP creates `<div id="ItemID"002>`, you need to fix that by changing it from `<div id= "ItemID" .$ItemID>` $ItemID  to `<div id='ItemID.$itemId'>`

**EDIT:** Also, I'd like to point out that in some places in your example, you forgot to use quotes when specifying the value of an attribute in HTML. I would recommend you fix that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can achieve this by javascript only. So you don't need to change markup or PHP.
Here is a sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L3bwfyve/

The key part is extraction of part of id of clicked element:

`var itemIdPart = e.target.id.substr(5);`

Be sure to check for nulls in `e.target` `id` etc...

Personally I would consider this solution a bit hacky... but you ask for javascrit, you get it ;-)